# ChangePassword method in Java

Tags: java, change-password

I'm working on a Java project, building a simple system, and it has some methods, one of them is "Change PassWord", I put the user's information (username & password) in a text file called ("Users.txt").
Now this is the description of the method:

> boolean ChangePassWord(): Asks the user to enter old password for
>   verification, the user has at maximum three tries to enter correct old
>   password; if not the password will not be changed and a message Box
>   will be shown for the user. If user entered correct old password then
>   he is authenticated to changer his password and asked to enter new
>   password and confirming the new. Once if confirmed correctly the old
>   password will be changed to the new one and a message box will be
>   shown if wrong confirmation the old password will not be changed and a
>   message box will be shown.

I wrote this code:

```
boolean changePassword(){            
  String pass=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter old password: ", "Input", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
  if(pass.equals(Password)) {
    String newpass=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
           "Enter new password: ", "Input", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    String connewpass=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
           "Enter confirming new password: ", "Input", 
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    if(newpass.equals(connewpass)){
      Password= newpass;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "password changed ", "message", 
          JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
      return true;
    }
    else
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Conferm ", "message", 
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

  }
  else
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong password ", "message", 
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

  return false;
}
```

but I think that it's wrong, and I need to use a loop I think.
I hope you help me!

Comment: What do you think is wrong with it?  How can we help?

Comment: I should give the user 3 tries if the password is wrong, so I need to add a loop, but how will I add it?

Comment: I think the logic is fine. I would just avoid storing plain passwords. You could use a simple cipher to store (like DES), and use the same on input password to compare both typed and store. Here is a simple class you can use to encrypt passwords: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/EncryptingaStringwithDES.htm

Comment: One detail about it ... if you use this approach you cannot recover forgotten password, you can only reset them (create new ones)

Answer (score 0):

A `while` loop is appropriate for your case. I will briefly explain how this `while` loop runs 3 times.

So, first `n=3`. The condition `n-- > 0` means 2 things. Check if n is greater than zero **and** subtract the value of n by 1. These 2 things happen in that exact order.

So the condition checks that n is indeed greater than zero and enters the loop. At the same time n is also decreased by 1 and becomes 3-1=2.

This goes on 3 times. After the 3rd time, n becomes 0. And the condition 0 > 0 is false and therefore the while loop breaks.

```
boolean changePassword(){            
  String pass = ""; //get old password from user
  int n = 3;
  while (n-- > 0) {
    if(pass.equals(Password)) {
        String newPass = ""; // get new password from user
        String conNewPass = ""; // confirm new password from user
        if (newPass.equals(conNewPass)) {
            Password = newPass;
            // password changed
            return true;
        } else {
            // wrong confirmation.. password not changed
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        // tell user to enter the correct old password
        pass = ""; // ask user for old password again
    }
  }
  // show error message that user entered the old password 3 times incorrectly
  // and return false
  return false;
}
```

Comment: This loop runs for one time, I tried to enter a wrong confirmation, or password, and The message appeared, then it stopped

Comment: `// tell the user to enter the correct old password` What do you think you should do here?

Comment: okay I asked the user to enter the password again, and it worked,, but now I only get the message "Wrong Password" whenever I type the password